# Passing Custom Attributes into Aurelia Component

Tags: aurelia

I'm having some trouble passing attributes into a custom component. I have tried declaring my component the following ways:

```
<require from="../components/project-documents"></require>

<project-documents projectId="testing123"></project-documents>
<project-documents projectId.bind="project.Name"></project-documents>
```

---

```
import {customElement, bindable} from "aurelia-framework";
import {autoinject} from "aurelia-dependency-injection";

@customElement("project-documents")
export class ProjectDocuments {

    @bindable projectId:string;

    attached() {
        alert(this.projectId);
    }
}
```

When the alert is called, undefined is the value I get from it. Also, is the customElement decorator required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using camelCase for your attributes, try dash-case.

Try this:

```
<project-documents project-id="testing123"></project-documents>
<project-documents project-id.bind="project.Name"></project-documents>
```

According to aurelia conventions, dash-case'd attributes will be converted to camelCase variables in your ViewModel, so your VM is already fine.

Comment: That did it! Where is that convention documented?

Comment: I'm sorry. I really though this convention was described in some of the docs pages, but it seems it's not. I must have read in some blog I can't find by now.

Comment: I think it is a blog. I remember seeing it as well awhile ago. Aurelia is still at the point you are piecing together documentation from wherever you can find it. :) It is pretty fun to use though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What sould be the model look like?

Comment: @ShahidKarimi The model remains the same as posted in the question